# We can't save this record because the "opportunity flow" process failed. The error msg is attached in imageHow can I fix this?

Tags: apex

I already bulkify the future method code but I am still getting this error

[image]

Future Method class

```
public class BQECase {
@future (callout=true)
public static void Send(List<Id> id,string operation){
   List<Case> caseSF= [select Id,SuppliedName,SuppliedPhone,SuppliedEmail,SuppliedCompany,AccountId,OwnerId,LastModifiedById,ContactId,Status,Reason,Subject,Description,BQECRM_ID__c,Product__c,AssignedTo__c,Employee__c,ProblemDesc__c,Solution__c,Jira_TicketNumber__c from Case Where Id =: id];
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    string endpoint= BqeGlobalManager.BqeApexEndPoint(operation, 'Case');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);             
  string body=JSON.serialize(caseSF);
  req.setBody(body);
  req.setTimeout(120000);
  if(!Test.IsRunningTest())
  {
   res = http.send(req);
       req.setCompressed(true);
  }
      
  
}
  @future (callout=true)
  public static void DeleteCase(Id id, string bqecrmId)
 {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    string endpoint= BqeGlobalManager.BqeApexEndPoint('Delete', 'Case');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);        
    Case caseSF=new Case(
        Id=id,
        BQECRM_ID__c= bqecrmId 
    );
    List<Case> caselist = new List<Case>();
    caselist.Add(caseSF);
    string body=JSON.serialize(caselist);
    req.setBody(body);
   if(!Test.IsRunningTest())
  {
   res = http.send(req);
       req.setCompressed(true);
  }     

}
```

}

Trigger

```
trigger BQECaseTrigger on Case (after insert,after update,after delete,before update) {


 if(Trigger.isBefore)
 {
     if(Trigger.isUpdate )
     {
     for(Case c : Trigger.New) {
      {
             c.UpdatedSource__c=c.Source__c;
             c.Source__c='';
      }
      return;
     }
    }
  }



if(Trigger.IsUpdate){
      Set<Id> allInsertedIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
        // if(allInsertedIds.size()<2)
         //{
       List<Id> ids=new List<Id>();
       for(Case c : Trigger.New) {
         if(c.UpdatedSource__c!='BQECRM')
         {
            ids.Add(c.id);                                
         }                 
       }
       if(!System.isBatch()){
          BQECase.Send(ids,'Update'); 
       } 
        // }
}
else if(Trigger.IsInsert){
    Set<Id> allInsertedIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
         //if(allInsertedIds.size()<2)
         //{
          List<Id> ids=new List<Id>();
            for(Case c : Trigger.New) { 
                ids.Add(c.id);    
                //BQECase.Send(c.id, 'Insert');                 
            } 
            if(!System.isBatch()){
                BQECase.Send(ids,'Insert'); 
           } 
            
 //} 
}
else if(Trigger.IsDelete){
     Set<Id> deletedIds = trigger.oldMap.keySet();
    if(deletedIds.size()<2){
     for(Case c : Trigger.old) { 
        BQECase.DeleteCase(c.Id,c.BQECRM_ID__c);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is all about calling a method annotated as `@future` from the named apex trigger. I am guessing this is a trigger wanting to perform a callout. Even if not, I suggest you read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) and look at the sample code linked at the end of the article.

Comment: @PhilW I have added the classe and trigger code to the question can you give me some specific insight what can be done.

Note we are getting this issues when we have around more than 10 milestones

Comment: So both `BQECase.Send` and `BQECase.DeleteCase` are future methods. As soon as you have more than 50 `Case` records deleted in a synchronous transaction your code will break. You can improve this by ensuring that you pass all cases for deletion in one go, like you have for insert and update. However, even then, if you have more than 50 calls to your trigger for insert or update in a single transaction it will break again. And you have specifically prevented updates being sent out if the trigger is called from a batch. There is a lot wrong with this. I recommend you read that article.

Comment: BTW, as I mentioned in the comment on your duplicate question (please don't do that in future), you should always ensure you provide error messages as text, not as screenshots, because the former is internet searchable and text in the latter is not.